# New expected value given condition (card game)

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, card-games

I have 15 distinct cards, each taking on a value of 1 to 15 (i.e. Card 1 has a value of 1, Card 2 has a value of 2, etc). I understand that expected value of each card is 8. Now say there are 5 players to whom each is dealt with a card. Each player only knows the value of his/her card. With 5 players, the expected value of all 5 cards is 40.


So let's suppose I am dealt with a card of value 15. Based on this known information, how can I then calculate the new expected value of all 5 cards? Theoretically, I know that it is definitely more than 40 since I am holding a 15.


Is the new expected value, given I am holding a 15, 45?

$\frac{(1+2+3+4+5...+13+14)}{14} \times 4 + 15 = 45$


Now say I also know the value of one of the other player's card (e.g. 3)
Is the new expected value, given I am holding a 15 and I know another value 3, calculated as follows:

$\frac{(1+2+4+5...+14)}{13} \times 3 + 15 + 3$ ?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct.

Comment: thanks marc! just needed to be sure.